# How do clear asp.net cache (cassini)

Tags: visual-studio

my application is loading the old javascript from cache everytime perssing f5 on visual studio.. hwo can i clear this stupid caching from VS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache is probably the *browser* cache - nothing to do with cassini. This would happen if you used IIS too.

You need to force reloads in the browser by using <kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd> in the browser.

Comment: @user384080 - Are you certain the browser is pointing to the latest location of the files?

Comment: mate.. i run my mvc app straight from visual studio by pressing f5.. i have even deleted the js file but it is still detecting while loading the page...   there must be a dir that stores the temp data..